# GetStream.io -- How is the colon to be used in the actor and to fields?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm a bit confused about the use of the colon in the GetStream.io examples and I'd like to clarify what should go in the `actor` field  -- is it the id of the actor or is it the id of the feed for that actor? E.g. If the actor has an id of `1` and a flat feed called `timeline:1`, would the actor have the value `1` or `timeline:1`?

In the GetStream.io examples, the colons in the `to` fields appear to separate the name of the feed group (e.g. `user` or `notification) from the id of the user (`playlist`, etc). In the examples, the colon in the`actor`field appear to separate the name of the model (e.g.`user`or`playlist`) from the id of the object. Am I correctly understanding the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Feeds are identified by the name of the feed group and the an id (often called user_id since feeds are in most scenarios bound to one user), making `feed_group:user_id`.

This is the only official use of colons for any other field you are free to use any value you prefer. In our examples the actor field is often populated by the feed identifier, but in real applications this field is mostly used to store a user identifier from your own application (i.e. the id a user has in your database). Stream doesn't enforce any specific format for this field it is up to you to decide how/what values to store. (also see: https://getstream.io/docs/#what-to-store)